# Component doesn't render properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, react-context

I'm new in using **React Context** and **Hooks** in my project. Currently I'm facing a problem when my item in the component doesn't display on the screen when it initially load but the item does display on the screen when I clicked on some button.

I did do some debugging using `console.log`and [in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziIBw.png), it did shows my data, but on the screen, it shows nothing. The weird part is, when I clicked on any button on the screen, [it finally show something on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2Erp.png).

Here is my code, in the OrderContext, I get all my data from Firestore.

```
//OrderContextProvider.js
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Firebase from "../component/misc/firebase";

export const OrderContext = createContext();

const OrderContextProvider = props => {
  const [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState({
    shop: "XXXXXXX"
  });
  const [food] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    userLocation.shop != null
      ? Firebase.firestore()
          .collection("restaurants")
          .doc(userLocation.shop)
          .collection("foods")
          .get()
          .then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
              food.push(doc.data());
            });
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
          })
      : console.log("User location unknown, please insert the location!");
  }, [food]);

  return (
    <OrderContext.Provider value={{ userLocation, food }}>
      {props.children}
    </OrderContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default OrderContextProvider;
```

and in Foods component, I tried get `food` from OrderContext and display `<Foods/>` in `<Home/>`

```
//foods.js
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { OrderContext } from "../../context/OrderContextProvider";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

const Foods = () => {
  const { food } = useContext(OrderContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(food);
  }, []);

  return food.map((foods, index) => {
    return (
      <Grid key={index} item xs={6} sm={6} md={3} xl={3} className="food">
        {foods.name}
      </Grid>
    );
  });
};

export default Foods;
```

```
//foods.js
 <Grid container className="container">
     <Foods/>
 </Grid>
```

May I know what is my mistake or what I missed out here? 
*Sorry for my bad English and thanks for reading*

Comment: Hi, can you post the full code in OrderContextProvider.js? I am interested in seeing how/where you have defined the context. I have a hunch on what's going on but need to see the code first.

Comment: @IshworTimilsina hi, I just updated the question, please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still unclear as to where/how you are using the OrderContextProvider component. But, one possible problem I see in the code is the way you are updating the "food" array. The way you are pushing items into it won't necessarily trigger the updates since you are not updating the state. You might want to do something like -

```
const OrderContextProvider = props => {
  ....
  const [food, setFood] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
      ...
          .then(function(querySnapshot) {
              let newFoods = [];
              querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                 newFoods.push(doc.data());
              });
              setFood([...food, ...newFoods]);
          })
      ...
  });
  ...
};
```

Comment: @nhk96 No problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
const food = [];
  useEffect(() => {
    userLocation.shop != null
      ? Firebase.firestore()
          .collection("restaurants")
          .doc(userLocation.shop)
          .collection("foods")
          .get()
          .then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
              food.push(doc.data());
            });
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
          })
      : console.log("User location unknown, please insert the location!");
  },[food]);
```

You have not passed second argument to the useEffect that tells the hook to run for the first time it loads.

I guess this is the reason why it's not showing the data on the first load.

Comment: Even if I passed the second argument in the useEffect, it still doesn't display my item on the screen. anyway, thanks!